# Easy way to switch endianess of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read the binary file, and write it's content in form of text file which will initialize memory model. Problem is, I need to switch endianess in process. Let's look at example
binary file content, when I read it with:

```py
with open(source_name, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent = file.read().hex()
```

filecontent: `"aa000000bb000000..."`.
I need, to transform that into `"000000aa000000bb..."`.
Of course, I can split this string into list of 8 chars substrings, than manualy reorganize it like `newsubstr = substr[6:8]+substr[4:6]+substr[2:4]+substr[0:2]`
, and then merge them into result string, but that seems clumsily, I suppose there is more natural way to do this in python.

Thanks to k1m190r, I found out about struct module which looks like what I need, but I still lost. I just designed another clumsy solution:

```py
with open(source_name, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent = file.read()
    while len(fileContent)%4 != 0:
        fileContent += b"\x00"
    res = ""
    for i in range(0,len(fileContent),4):
        substr = fileContent[i:i+4]
        substr_val = struct.unpack("<L", substr)[0]
        res += struct.pack(">L", substr_val).hex()
```

Is there a more elegant way? This solution is just slightly better than the original.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html is your friend

Comment: @k1m190r, thank your for your comment! Can you look in my updated post to check my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your specific case you don't even need `struct`. Below should be sufficient.

```py
from binascii import b2a_hex

# open files in binary 
with open("infile", "rb") as infile, open("outfile", "wb") as outfile:

    # read 4 bytes at a time till read() spits out empty byte string b""
    for x in iter(lambda: infile.read(4), b""):
        if len(x) != 4:
            # skip last bit if it is not 4 bytes long
            break
        outfile.write(b2a_hex(x[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant way? This solution is just slightly better than the original

Alternatively, you can craft a "smarter" struct format string: format specifiers take a number prefix which is the number of repetitions e.g. `10L` is the same as `LLLLLLLLLL` so you can inject the size of your data divided by 4 before the letter and and convert the entire thing in one go (or a few steps, I don't know how big the counter can be).

`array.array` might also work as that's what the `byteswap, but you can't specify the input endianness (I think), so it's iffier.

Comment: Problem is, I cant hardcode a concrete value, I need a way to write this value from a variable...Well, I can use `format` method I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question:

```
import re
changed = re.sub(b'(....)', lambda x:x.group()[::-1], bindata)
```

- Note: original had `r'(....)'` when the `r` should have been `b`.

Comment: As I see, what you suggest is just reverse substring, but I need to reverse substring by pairs. E.g. abcdef01 in your suggestion will transform into 10fedcba, when I need 01efcdab.

Comment: don't convert it to hex before calling sub and you should get bytes. Call hex after,
```bindata = file.read()
changed = re.sub(r'(....)', lambda x:x.group()[::-1], bindata).hex()```

Comment: If I do so, I will end up with exception: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object. Or I still doing something wrong.

Comment: Quite right. Change the 'r' to 'b'. `changed = re.sub(b'(....)', lambda x:x.group()[::-1], bindata)`